# How to make the tab widget width fill parent in android

Tags: android-tabhost

I have created a TabWidget at the bottom of layout. There are 5 tabs in the tab widget. But these tabs are not occupying the full width. the xml file is as follows :

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
     <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <FrameLayout
           android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:padding="5dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TabWidget
           android:id="@android:id/tabs"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="0"
           android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</TabHost>
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that removing the android:padding="5dp" tag from both your linearlayout and framelayout should do what you're looking for...

So you'd be looking at this

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
     <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <FrameLayout
           android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TabWidget
           android:id="@android:id/tabs"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="0"
           android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</TabHost>
```